# Amazon Connect Contact Flow - Set Voice based on an attribute?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect, amazon-polly

I'm setting up a contact flow, and I noticed there is the Set Voice block which let's you select which voice from Polly you want to use.

However, I want to be able to dynamically change the voice by passing an attribute with the Voice ID. Is this possible?

The only thing I can think of would be to create a duplicate contact flow for each voice I want to use but that seems like way too much work than it should be.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an attribute in the Set Voice block directly, so you would need to use the Check Contact Attribute block and conditionally branch your flow to a Set Voice Block that has the desired settings.

[image: Contact Flow Screenshot]